# Inner pages redirect on 404 page in Magento 1.9 after change base url for non primary domain in Godaddy

Tags: .htaccess, magento-1.9

I am using non primary domain for Magento setup. On demo server Magento working fine. But once I changed the link of base url Magento not working. I tried to find issue in htaccess file but no luck. I am not familiar with Magento.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Need to confirm base url link in core_config_data table.

check following path and value columns are as below.

Unsecured
path = 'web/unsecure/base_url'
value = 'http://domainname/'

Secured
path = 'web/secure/base_url'
value = 'http://domainname/'

2. Cleared cache from below path in root folder.

/var/cache/

3. IF still not working then cleared session from below path.

/var/session/